# Dimensional analysis

Tags: resource-recommendations, dimensional-analysis

I was recently introduced to [dimensional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) and I wanted good references for learning the ideas behind it and representation of the natural world. I'm a grad student in biology. I don't have much of a physics background.

Comment: Dimensional analysis is applicable to every field, not just biology or physics. Probably the best reference is to search the web for 1st year courses that deal with a lot of math. In the first couple of weeks of the course, the concept will have been explained.

Comment: I don't normally recommend it, but this is one of the rare circumstances when [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) has a great article on the subject...

Answer (score 6):

This is a great summary of dimensional analysis written by Ain Sonin, a former professor of mechanical engineering at MIT. It's only ~50 pages, and most of it should be accessible to you. Though some examples may draw on parts of physics you're not familiar with, it is very well-written and should clarify the subject greatly.

http://web.mit.edu/2.25/www/pdf/DA_unified.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A very good book, with more than 200 worked-out examples, is 'Applied Dimensional Analysis and Modeling' by Thomas Szirtes, MacGraw Hill, ISBN 0-07-062811-4